# В каких случаях пишутся квадратные скобки в Python?

Tags: python

В каких случаях пишутся квадратные скобки в Python?

Comment: В тех, где это допустимо по синтаксису и уместно в контексте решаемой задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Тогда, когда создается/используется список как тип данных, подробнее можешь почитать, загуглив "списки Python" или [по ссылке.](https://pythonworld.ru/tipy-dannyx-v-python/spiski-list-funkcii-i-metody-spiskov.html)

Comment: В очереди проверок вам могут указать, что это ответ-ссылка. Я ответил "выглядит нормально", т.к. начало ответа пусть и кратко, но говорит про использование скобок в списках - из очереди проверок.

Comment: `typing.Optional[typing.Dict[str, typing.List[int]]]` немного не согласен с вами :)

Comment: @AK Спасибо большое :)